# Write to MongoDB using Spark Connector and Append mode

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, connector

I am new to MongoDB Spark Connector and as far as I understand there is two ways to write to the DB [LINK](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/v2.0/scala/write-to-mongodb/), one way is:

```
MongoSpark.save(documents)
```

which can be extended to

```
MongoSpark.save(df.write.option("collection", "myCollection").mode("append"))
```

and another way using the Using the RDDs helper method, which goes something like this:

```
documents.saveToMongoDB(WriteConfig(Map("uri" -> "mongodb://example.com/database.collection")))
```

I would like to know whether it is possible to specify the "mode("append")" in the RDDs helper method (Second way) and if yes How?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already solved this problem. Anyhow, you should use both the WriteConfig and dataframewriter to inform Mongo that you want to append documents to the collection.

You can do this by using the overloaded save method with both dataframewriter and writeconfig:

```
MongoSpark.save(df.write.mode("append"), WriteConfig(Map("uri" -> "mongodb://[uri-string]")))
```